# HTML Image: Set height to 16:10 ratio of 100% width | using css/js

Tags: image, resize, height, width

sorry if this has been asked a zillion times. i am unable to find a satisfactory answer.

whats the simple and efficient way to display any and all images in 16:10 ratio on page, where the width of image is set to x% (responsive design).

so basically how to work on height. instead of `height: auto`, use `height: width*10/16` or something. or any other solution that makes this possible with little code and effort.
using either CSS or JS or even PHP.

for example, this div with img's:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img540/2396/OrosLf.jpg" />
    <img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img908/5868/G92vQu.jpg" />
</div>
```

wit hthis CSS:

```
div { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
img {
    display: block; float: left;
    background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #555;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
}
```

heres the fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shadez/tosysrwo/1/)

PS: i did check object-fit but i guess its not well supported? - [caniuse objectfit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)